# Can't make Gdal 1.11.2 work from binaries

Tags: python, django, gdal, geos

I am trying to install GEOS for Django project and following [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) but while compiling on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial I get this error. There was some fix for it [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/34426) but it also didn't worked. Following is the error I get while I ran "make" as per official Django docs.

Error:

```
    gdalserver.c: In function 'CreateSocketAndBindAndListen':
gdalserver.c:125:21: error: storage size of 'sHints' isn't known
     struct addrinfo sHints;
                     ^
gdalserver.c:127:31: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct addrinfo'
     memset(&sHints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
                               ^
gdalserver.c:130:23: error: 'AI_PASSIVE' undeclared (first use in this function)
     sHints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
                       ^
gdalserver.c:130:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
gdalserver.c:133:12: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     nRet = getaddrinfo(NULL, pszService, &sHints, &psResults);
            ^
gdalserver.c:136:48: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gai_strerror' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(nRet));
                                                ^
gdalserver.c:136:25: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
         fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo(): %s\n", gai_strerror(nRet));
                         ^
gdalserver.c:142:39: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct addrinfo'
          psResultsIter = psResultsIter->ai_next)
                                       ^
gdalserver.c:163:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'freeaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     freeaddrinfo(psResults);
     ^
gdalserver.c:125:21: warning: unused variable 'sHints' [-Wunused-variable]
     struct addrinfo sHints;
                     ^
../GDALmake.opt:565: recipe for target 'gdalserver.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [gdalserver.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/osboxes/gdal-1.11.2/apps'
GNUmakefile:69: recipe for target 'apps-target' failed
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try version GDAL 2.2.2. The version you are trying is not maintained. Also try to upgrade all the version of software you are using. There is a reason for patches and upgrades so keep always updated versions.